# How to make a query with Google Spreadsheet, that checks for a date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a range that goes from `B4:H124`. All the cells in column B are dates. I would like to retrieve the data from a row (`B:H`), where the DATE equals to the content of a specific cell, lets say Q4.

How do I construct a proper query?

So far, what I have come up with this:

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select * where B = date '2012-02-28'")
```

It works, even though the format of the cells in B is DD/MM/YYYY.

How can I change `2012-02-28` to `$Q4`? When I try, I get the following error:

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select * where B = date '"&Q4&"'")

Invalid query: Invalid date literal [10/02/2012]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd.
```

When I look at the cell, the format is `yyyy-mm-dd`, but when I doubleclick it, the format changes to `DD-MM-YYYY`.

What should I do?

Also, how can I sum up the values from the query, without including column B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the trick for the real date cell to work yet, but you could have a work around if nothing else by adding the the single quote (`'`) before the date in a format: `YYYY-MM-DD` in the `Q4` cell.

That single quote means that the it will be parsed as string.

Answer (score 14):

You can format the date like this:

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select * where B = date '" & text(Q4,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")
```

To sum up the values in column C, do this:

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select sum(C) where B = date '" & text(Q4,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")
```

Not sure how to sum up multiple columns though - still pretty new to this myself!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`=QUERY(B2:G124; "select * where B = date '"&text(Q4;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")`

Anyway, I had the same problem and finally it worked for me.

The thing is that you get confused by the message

```
Invalid query: Invalid date literal [10/02/2012]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd.
```

This is because your Q4 cell's date format seems to be dd/MM/yyyy. I have the same thing: even if this looks like being dd/MM/yyyy you just have to put it like it's given in the second line of my reply herein above.

Answer (score 1):

Put your desired date in a new cell like `Q3` in this format: `2/28/2012`

Then in the `Q4` cell type `=YEAR(Q3) & "-" & DEC2OCT(MONTH(Q3), 2) & "-" & DAY(Q3)`

This will get the date from the `Q3` cell and convert it to a string in the `Q4` cell.

This is more helpful if you want the current date. Instead of getting the date from `Q3` your can use `now()` to get today's date like so: `=YEAR(now()) & "-" & DEC2OCT(MONTH(now()), 2) & "-" & DAY(now())`

Answer (score 1):

The final should be:

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select * where B = date ' "  & text( Q4 ,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")
```

Where Q4 is a normal date formatted cell where you may type in a date.

Copy the above to your notepad and enlarge the font size to what's all about.

It's hard to see the single `'` within the double `"` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also calculate the date outside the string and drop the `date`, for example

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select * where B = '" & Q4)
```

Q4 effectively gets passed as an integer, which is what QUERY transforms the date to behind the scenes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google's QUERY function:

To `sum` **multiple columns**, it's important to include the `label` parameter at the end of the query

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select sum(C) + sum(D) + sum(E) + sum(F) + sum(G) label sum(C) + sum(D) + sum(E) + sum(F) + sum(G) '' ")
```

*note: column references are case sensitive & the 2 single quotes at the end of the query are required.*

To add a `where` clause referencing a cells **date** value: *from s6mikes solution*

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select * where B = date '" & text(Q4,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "')
```

**The 2 queries combined**...

```
=QUERY(B2:G124; "select sum(C) + sum(D) + sum(E) + sum(F) + sum(G) where B = date '" & text(Q4,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' label sum(C) + sum(D) + sum(E) + sum(F) + sum(G) '' ")
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the type of data in your reference cell to text. And it will work smoothly.